# Duplicate keys with Amazon Athena and Open JSONx Serde

Tags: hive, amazon-athena, presto

I have the following data due to an error:

```
{
  "eventType": "something",
  "details": {
    "userName": "NotSet",
    "username": "test@email.com"
  },
  "createdAt": 3
}
```

Creating the table works:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tbl (
         eventType string,
         `createdAt` string,
         details string 
) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
 LOCATION 's3://xx/yy'
```

However when I query (tried details to string, struct, map, always same) I get the duplicate key error:

```
HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR: Row is not a valid JSON Object - JSONException: Duplicate key "username"
```

They are duplicate if you use them as row columns, but not as map keys, or even string, why does it fail? The `org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe` can skip but I do not like it since %99.5 data is like this. The `org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe` fails always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's now possible to set a parameter in order to cater for keys that only differs by the case. The name is `case.insensitive` and should be set to `FALSE`

Example:

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("case.insensitive" = "FALSE")
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/json-serde.html#openx-json-serde

Answer (score 1):

Presto does not support case sensitive column names (they are always converted to lowercase), so it’s not possible to multiple columns that differ only by case.

Comment: But map keys should not be columns?